# Proguard with orrmlite - parameterized Collection

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite

My app works perfectly without proguard. When I use proguard with ormlite, I have some problems. In the logcat appear:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field class for 'name' must be a parameterized Collection
```

In proguard file I put:

```
-keep class com.j256.** 
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found you need to keep more than just the *Annotation* attribute

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
```

Below is my default ormlite proguard statements. You need to keep the files that describe your data as well

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod 
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

-keep class com.mycompany.myproduct.data.entity.**
-keepclassmembers class com.mycompany.myproduct.data.entity.** { *; }
-keep enum com.mycompany.myproduct.data.entity.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.mycompany.myproduct.data.entity.** { *; }
-keep interface com.mycompany.myproduct.data.entity.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.mycompany.myproduct.data.entity.** { *; }
```